# Writing filtered results to a file in python. Filtering based on 2 variables

Tags: python, json, if-statement, filter

### **Intro**

Hi Stackoverflow! I was here a time ago for a previous piece of code that I got working :)
This is another piece of code, but somewhat based on the previous one.

---

**Old script**

Here it is for the people wondering:

```
from pysnap import Snapchat

s = Snapchat()

username = raw_input('Enter username: ')
password = raw_input('Enter password: ')
s.login(username, password)
snaps = s.get_snaps()

for sender in snaps:
    if sender['media_type'] == 3:
        s.add_friend(sender[u'sender'])
```

It's pretty straight forward, get_snaps() gives us results from which we can conclude if someone has send us a **friend request** , because somehow snapchat thought that friend-requests fits **media**_type 3.

---

**New plan**

Anyway, on to my new code, which is based on this.

I was looking to make a script that filter privacy settings on usernames.
Partly to show how important those are in snapchat.

Privacy settings have either a value of 0 **or** 1. 0 meaning your privacy settings are set to "everyone" and 1 meaning they are set to "friends only".
I want to be able to save the usernames accordingly in the appropriate files.

---

**Responses**

When I add a username it gives me the following response:

**Privacy settings set to 0 (everyone)**

```
{u'logged': True,
 u'message': u'dummyname is now your friend!',
 u'object': {u'can_see_custom_stories': True,
             u'direction': u'OUTGOING',
             u'display': u'dummyname',
             u'name': u'dummyname',
             u'source': u'SEARCHED_BY_USERNAME',
             u'type': 0}}
```

**Settings set to private:**

```
{u'logged': True,
 u'message': u'dummyname is private. Friend request sent.',
 u'object': {u'can_see_custom_stories': True,
             u'direction': u'OUTGOING',
             u'display': u'',
             u'name': u'dummyname',
             u'source': u'SEARCHED_BY_USERNAME',
             u'type': 1}}
```

**Invalid username:**

```
{u'logged': False, u'message': u"Sorry! Couldn't find sdlkjsdl;jkaslkjwe"}
```

---

**Where am I now?**

This is what I have thus far for filtering and adding the valid username to the according file and discarding the invalid username:

```
from pysnap import Snapchat

#Get data needed to login and add friend.
username = raw_input('Enter username: ')
password = raw_input('Enter password: ')
someone = raw_input('Enter friend: ')

#Stating s
s = Snapchat()

#Logging in
s.login(username, password)

#Stating resp
resp = s.add_friend(someone)

#Filter json response
#Adding username to file accordingly
for name in resp:
    if name['type'] == 1: #PRIVACY_FRIENDS = 1
        with open ('private.txt', 'a') as f: f.write (name[u'name'])
    elif name['type'] == 0: #PRIVACY_EVERYONE = 0
         with open ('n-private.txt', 'a') as f: f.write (name[u'name'])
    else: #Don't do anything but just tell me it's an invalid username.
        print "Not a valid username"
```

---

**Current error(s)**

```
$ Traceback (most recent call last):
$   File "responseaddfriend.py", line 20, in <module>
$     if name['type'] == 1: #PRIVACY_FRIENDS = 1
$ TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

---

**What have I tried?**

I have tried to delete the `name` in front of `name['type']`

Which resulted in:

```
$ Not a valid username
$ Not a valid username
$ Not a valid username
```

Without writing anything to the files.

---

**Additional -maybe- helpful information.**

Unofficial API I'm working with:

```
https://github.com/martinp/pysnap/blob/master/pysnap/__init__.py
```

Friend values.

```
FRIEND_CONFIRMED = 0
FRIEND_UNCONFIRMED = 1
FRIEND_BLOCKED = 2
PRIVACY_EVERYONE = 0
PRIVACY_FRIENDS = 1
```

---

### Final word before posting this question.

Dear Stackoverflow community, I have tried my best before asking this question, even though "what have I tried?" section is pretty small.

I have researched a lot already and consulted the python tutorial / manual page but could not figure this out on my own.

I am posting this question because I truly believe I can not figure this out on my own without getting too frustrated and spending days on it.

It has been pointed out to me that previous questions lacked some additional details, which I hope to have taken care of the right way in this question.
If not, please leave a comment on where I can improve when asking a question.

Even though this might seem like a "noob" question to some of you, please understand that you had to start somewhere as well, and I truly appreciate every response I get because eventually it will make me a better coder.

**Thank you.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the resp object completely incorrectly.

Try this instead:

```
if 'object' in resp.keys():
    # 'object' is contained within resp as a key
    if resp['object']['type']:
        # type is 1
        with open ('private.txt', 'a') as f: f.write(resp['object']['name'])
    else:
        # type is 0
        with open ('n-private.txt', 'a') as f: f.write(resp['object']['name'])
else:
    # no object in resp, so it's an invalid username
    print 'Not a valid username.'
```

For future reference, try your code in the Python shell before putting it into a script so it's easier to tell where the errors are happening!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, it seems to be working. May I ask, how does the "filtering" happen here, aka; how does python know what is "0" and what is "1"

Comment: The only problem now is that it does not go to a new line for the next account in line, adding + "/n" just places a /n behind the username

Comment: if 0 is like saying if False, if 1 is like saying if True :-)